# Overwriting XMLHttpRequest.responseText

Tags: javascript

I'll do my best to explain my problem but if I'm honest, I'm a little confused myself so I can't imagine it'll be much easier for you guys.

Right, I'm creating a script for a userscript for a website I frequent. What I'm trying to do is hijack any ajax requests, which I'm doing fine and then modify the responseText.

I can't seem to write to responseText, I can read it fine and it shows the response fine but I can't change it's value no matter what I try.

I get no errors in the console, I've left comments in my code to show what does log.

I was just going to scrap it but knowing me, I've missed something stupidly obvious and just can't see it.

Thanks in advance.

```
(function(send) { 
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) { 
        this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() { 
            if(typeof data == 'string'){
                if(data.indexOf('room.details_1') > -1){
                    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                        console.log('Before: ' + JSON.parse(this.responseText).body.user.profile.username); // Shows NameNumber1
                        var temp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        temp.body.user.profile.username = 'NameNumber2';
                        this.responseText = JSON.stringify(temp);
                        console.log('Temp: ' + temp.body.user.profile.username); // Shows NameNumber2
                        console.log('After: ' + JSON.parse(this.responseText).body.user.profile.username); // Shows NameNumber1 <-- This is the problem.
                        console.log(this); // Shows the XMLHttpRequest object, with the original responseText rather than the modified one.
                    }
                }
            }
        }, false);
        send.call(this, data);
    }; 
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

Comment: This sounds a bit fishy to say the least.

Comment: It's not fishy, it's client-side. Any effects would only affect me

Comment: Well, unless you inject it somewhere else.

Comment: I guess but I assure you my intentions are pure.

Comment: In Firefox, when I view the  property descriptors of its prototype using `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()`, it appears to be set up as a "getter" with no "setter", so you won't be able to write to that property.

Comment: ...however the property is marked as `configurable`, so that should provide the means to create a workaround.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on that @cookiemonster? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Here's a demo that you can work from: http://jsfiddle.net/yA2GD/ I grabbed the default "getter" function, kept a reference to it, then assigned a new getter and a setter. The setter now sets a `._custom_text` property, and the new getter returns the `._custom_text` if it exists, or otherwise calls the original getter to get the actual value. You can tweak it to change its behavior.

Comment: @cookiemonster that should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you, it's getting quite late here so I might need to leave it till the morning. Thanks again :) You've been very helpful.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: While vague, the accepted answer does refer to overriding `XMLHttpRequest`. I'm willing to assume overriding the default behaviors defined on the `.prototype` is what was meant. But thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: @user2984236: You're welcome. To be clear, the code I provided would be invoked before any XHR requests are made, and invoked only once. It modifies the `XMLHttpRequest.prototype` object, so all objects created from that constructor will automatically get the new behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest.responseText` is ReadOnly. This means there is no setter and therefore you can not modify its value. There is no workaround except you override `XMLHttpRequest` itself.

[Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest1/#xmlhttprequest)

**Edit**
Test for the suggestion to use `Object.defineProperty` to override `responseText`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
Object.defineProperty( xhr, "responseText", { value: "test" });
xhr.responseText // returns ""
```

So this won't work either

Comment: Alright, thank you. That's frustrating but it helps. I appreciate it. I'll accept this answer when it lets me.

Comment: Are you sure you can't override that with a `Object.defineProperty`? That usually works with read only properties.

Comment: see edit, tested in Chrome 37, seems, that its sealed or `responseText` is `configurable:false`

Comment: It seems that a possible workaround for Chrome would be `xhr = Object.create(xhr, {responseText:{value:"foo"}});`

Answer (score 5):

I know this is 3 years too late, but I Have included it here for anyone else that comes across this thread.  I've done this before... Here is a copy and paste directly from my script.  You should be able to just change the responseText to be writable.

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "responseText", {writable: true});
this.responseText = '{"success":true}';
```

Comment: This works great! Is this new or not supported by every browser, or how come this simple solution is not more well-known?

Comment: I usually use mine specifically for chrome Userscripts/Extensions, but based on (http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Object.defineProperty) it looks like you can probably use it pretty widespread and for a while now because it is apart of ECMAScript 5

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me in chrome:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
delete request.responseText;
request.responseText = 'test';
request.responseText; // returns 'test'
```